# How to interpret the text on this "희창기계" (Huichang Machine)?

Tags: translation, character-meanings

I found this photograph of a machine (which produces plastic pipes) on [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40077/translate-into-English):

[image: 희창기계]

I know that 기계(gigye, 機械) means 'Machine', but I am unsure how to interpret the other text in "희창기계". (when I  search for "Huichang Machine", I get many results that look like company names).

- What are the Chinese characters for "희창" （Huichang） ?
- Right beneath the company name [ T. 854 - 1904 ] <-- What's this? Telephone number? . . . Product number ?

<sub>I got interested because i thought it was a grave (tombstone) of a legendary figure who lived for 1000+ years. w w w</sub>

Comment: I would say that T. 854 - 1904 is almost surely the telephone number.

Comment: Some comments [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46996/discussion-on-question-by-hizha-how-to-interpret-the-text-on-this--huicha).

Answer (score 5):

I found following information on google.
(you can find more on google)

- http://bizkorea.org/company/view.asp?SEQ=665962

It seems that '희창기계' is a very small korean company located in [Daegu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daegu)
and T.354-1904 is surely their telephone number. In Korea, very small local companies usually omit area codes in their telephone number, as they really don't need to advertize where their company is.

Comment: Good detective work! I think it's *354* 1904?

Answer (score 4):

1. I'm pretty sure that 희창(Huichang) is a name of a male person. I(Korean) had a friend named 희창. I don't know the Chinese characters for the name, though. So, 희창기계 must be a company founded by a guy named 희창 like Hewlett-Packard or Dell or Procter & Gamble.
2. T. 854 - 1904 is a telephone number. "T." is frequently used for phone number in Korea. Since that phone number doesn't have the area code, it's probably a phone number in Seoul. Sometimes Seoulites just omit the area code.

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you.  When I search for "Huichang Machine", I only get 6 hits and all of them are: Shanghai Huichang Machine Equipment Co., Ltd. ( China ). __________________ So I've come to the tentative conclusion (or a guess) that it's actually a Chinese company, and that Huichang is Chinese.  It sounds more Chinese than Korean to me.  Thanks again.